# Reflection from DTO

Tags: c#, reflection, dto

I have 1 dto, `statEMailDTO`, which has a field that holds the Field Names of what I'm looking for (they are comma delimited.

```
var emailParams = statEmailDTO.EmailParam.ToString().Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < emailParams.Length; i++) {
  var fieldName = emailParams[i].ToString();
```

etc.

But, then how do I use Reflection to then get the Actual value of ``fieldName which is found in a different DTO, siDTO.

So let's say that `fieldName = "SuggestionItemID"`, I then what to get the value of `siDTO.SuggestionItemID`.

I haven't done a lot of reflection in the past. Sure, I read up on PropertyInfo, but it's just not clicking.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
PropertyInfo property = typeof(SomeType).GetProperty(fieldName);
object value = property.GetValue(instance, null);
```

Comment: But, what is SomeType? and what is instance?

Comment: @Patrick: `SomeType` is the type that owns the property, and `instance` is the instance whose value you want to get.

Comment: if I do the following... var fieldName = emailParams[i].ToString(); System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = typeof(SuggestionItemDTO).GetProperty(fieldName); object fieldValue = property.GetValue(fieldName, null);  then I get an "object does not match target type" Error. Thoughts? I mean I realy want the value of siDTO."fieldName"

Comment: I got it! Holly crap: System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = typeof(SuggestionItemDTO).GetProperty(fieldName);

                    object fieldValue = property.GetValue(siDTO, null);